# How does mongodb replica set react in this scenario?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Given the scenario of a typical replica set (one primary, one secondary and one arbiter) in which 3 members are deployed on 3 independent network nodes. If the network connection between primary and secondary is broken, while anything else is all good, how does mongodb react?

Under this circumstances, the arbiter knows the primary and the secondary are both alive, and the primary is not actually impacted although it will continue reporting the disconnection of secondary, but to the secondary, will it trigger an election to be the primary? Then what happens to the original primary? and so on.

I can't figure out what will happen, and this scenario is hard to create on my PC. Dose anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a three node replica set, as long as two members can see each other (and one of those is a data-bearing node) a primary can be elected.

So possible scenarios with one node being fully disconnected:

- If *primary* and *arbiter* can see other (but not the *secondary*), there is no election but the *secondary* will start to accumulate replication lag until the network connection is restored (or the *secondary's* [oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#replica-set-oplog-sizing) no longer has a common point with the *primary* and has to be [re-synced](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-resync-stale-member)).
- If *primary* and *secondary* can see each other (but not the *arbiter*), there is no election and replication will continue normally.
- If *secondary* and *arbiter* can see other (but not the *primary*), the *secondary* will be elected as a primary.  If there was replication lag, there may be some entries written on the former primary that were not accepted on the secondary.  When the former primary is able to rejoin the replica set (as a secondary) any operations that were not replicated to the current primary will be saved as a [rollback](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#replica-set-rollback).

In the event of a partial disconnect where the *primary* and *secondary* can see the *arbiter* but not each other, I would expect that the *secondary* will try to start an election but get vetoed because the *arbiter* can see an active *primary* which is newer than the *secondary* (if any node vetoes, the election fails).

There is a trickier case when the network availability is inconsistent.  In this case the replica set may experience "flapping" (successive elections) if the primary is intermittently unreachable.

One way to simulate network scenarios is using firewall rules (for blocking) and tools such as [`tc` (traffic control](http://lartc.org/manpages/tc.txt) to introduce delay or packet loss.  There is also a `mongobridge` tool you can compile in the MongoDB source tree (see: [Simulating Network Partitions with mongobridge](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/04/20/simulating-network-paritions-with-mongobridge/)).

Other useful reading:

- [Kristina Chudorow's Replica Set Internals Bootcamp: Part I – Elections](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2012/01/04/replica-set-internals-bootcamp-part-i-elections/).
- [Server Density: Avoiding Flapping](http://blog.serverdensity.com/avoiding-flapping/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is answered by this bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9730
"under any circumstances, do not vote yea while a primary already exists", so there won't be two primary.